# Creating a MATLAB program using Euler Explicit Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, optimal-control, economics

[image]I want to solve following ODE using Euler explicit method.
$$S'(t)=\frac{b}{m}\bigg(u(t)+\frac{P(t)}{p}\bigg)$$
where $S(0)=\frac{q}{m}$.
We can have any value for the parameters. $P(t)$ should be a non-decreasing function. I don't understand how to introduce the function in the program. Suppose $P(t)=t$ then what will be the formula of Euler explicit method?
MATLAB Code:

```
T = 10;
N = 100;
h = T/N;
b = -1;
q = 1;
m = 1;
p = 1.5;

S(0) = q/m;
S(1)=s(0);

for j=1:N
   aj    =(j-1)*h;
   S(j+1)=(b*h/p*m)*t(j) + S(j);
end
```

I have written this code. I have taken the simplest case taking $u(t)=0$. But I am confused about $P(t)$. I have taken $P(t)=t$ as a non decreasing function. But how I have to introduced it? Do I have to give an initial value for t also?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The ODE you give and the update formula do not match - either the formula you give is wrong, or the implementation.

Comment: I have taken u(t)=0 so the equation becomes S'(t)=bP(t)/mp

Answer (score 1):

For a step length of `h = T/N` (note that in this form $N$ does not count the initial time $t=0$) the Forward Euler update equation reads in general form

```
S(j + 1) = S(j) + h * b/m * (u(j) + P(j) / p)
```

and for $u(t) \equiv 0$ and $P(t) = t$

```
S(j + 1) = S(j) + h * b/m * (t_0 + j * h) / p
```